# ProgressDialog updating in onProgressUpdate, recounting when big size file downloading in Android

Tags: android, android-asynctask, download, progressdialog

I'm writing program to download large size of file (~ 280 MB) from a remote server. Downloading process working perfectly although it takes lot of time. Then I used a `ProgressDialog` to show the current state of the downloading process. It is also perfectly working for small size file downloading. "perfect" in the sense, showing the downloaded amount as a percentage and 100% download. But that is not working for that big file size downloading.

The issue is, it shows the progress till 7% and then start counting the progress again. But in the background, downloading is happening normally.

I can't figure out what/where is the mistake. Because the same code working for small size files. Can anybody please give me a clue?

Thank you

Comment: It will be greatly helpful if you include code snippet.

Comment: Sorry guys, I've done a mistake. 
I am counting download amount and assign it to int variable. 
For larger files, it exceed the positive int limit (2,147,483,647). After that the value become minus (-). 
Then it will not display in my progress dialog. 
This does not occur for small size files where total count of the download not exceed positive int range.
So I assign the total count for long variable as a solution.
Thanks for the people who try to help.